# failure in sdio_enable_func() for WIfi driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, embedded-system

I am new to use wifi cards. My embedded linux device detects Vendor ID and Product ID of the Wifi module but while I try to load the wifi driver, I am getting log indicating failure in `sdio_enable_func()`.

On further debug. I found that the driver source code tries to write 2 on `SDIO CCCR IOEX` register. It is successfull but `SDIO CCCR IORx` function remains 0.

Can anyone tell me what will be the reason for the failure in this process?